# How do you actually show that the complement of the set of condensation points of an uncountable set in $\mathbf R$ is at most countable?

Tags: general-topology

I can show that the condensation points form a perfect set, but can't show this. This question may have duplicates in stackexchange but apparently has no detailed answer. Any solution will be appreciated. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal I$ be the family of all open intervals with rational endpoints whose intersection with the uncountable set $A$ is countable.  Note that $B = \bigcup_{I \in \mathcal I} (I \cap A)$ is a countable union of countable sets, and is therefore countable. Now observe that each point of $A \setminus B$ is a condensation point of $A$.

(Note that all we are really using here is that $\mathbb R$ is second-countable.)

Answer (score 0):

Just note that the set of condensation points of X can be obtained by removing all intervals with rational end points in which X has countably many points.